# How to query all permission for security group (Role), when groups are hierarchical (group can include another groups)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data

I have 3 tables: Users, Groups and Permissions

and many to many relationships: UserGroups, GroupPermissions.

```
CREATE TABLE [Users]
(
  UserId INT Primary Key
)
CREATE TABLE [Groups]
(
  GroupId INT Primary Key
)
CREATE TABLE [UserGroups]
(
  UserId INT, GroupId INT
  PRIMARY KEY (UserId, GroupId)
)
CREATE TABLE [GroupPermissions]
(
  GroupId INT, PermissionId INT
  PRIMARY KEY (GroupId, PermissionId)
)
```

User permissions can be queried using:

```
SELECT GroupPermissions.PermissionId FROM [UserGroups]
INNER JOIN [Groups] ON [UserGroups].GroupId = Groups.GroupId
INNER JOIN [GroupPermissions] ON [Groups].GroupId = [GroupPermissions].GroupId
WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

### THE QUESTION:

I want to add GroupGroups, so that **groups could include another groups** (like security groups in Active Directory for example).

How do I query all user permissions by userId?

Comment: Have you tried a recursive CTE to get all of the `Groups` related to the `UserId` and returning all of the associated `Permissions`? The CTE _anchor_ query would be from `UserGroups` and the _recursive_ query from `GroupGroups`. For extra credit you might want to defend against cycles, e.g. bosses includes managers includes executives includes bosses includes ... .

Comment: @HABO: I didn't know about recursive CTEs. Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: I'd rather that you try solving the problem rather than posting "I want to add ...".

Comment: Can you do this? Yes. Should you? Maybe not. This will make tracking permissions quite tricky to manage. Just think, how will your users administer permissions? If they have permission 123 and want to remove it, where is it coming from?  Is it because they are in group A or because Group A is in Group B which is in Group C? Then think about audits of who has what and when? It all gets very tricky very fast. If you need to do this, will highly recommend using the ```HIERARCHYID``` data type. Most apps will require frequent permission checks and it will greatly speed up those queries

Comment: @Stephan: This is common way of managing permissions (LDAP, AAD, many others...). 
I was considering HIERARCHYID (never used it so far), but from what I understand it is not suitable for many:many:many relationships. Could you draft a solution using `HIERARCHYID`?

Comment: Not saying this is bad design, but it introduces more complexity than most people realize, and so need to account for that. HID has plenty of tutorials on how to setup online. By the end, you’ll need 3 columns in your schema: ID, ParentID, and HID. HID in way duplicates info from ParentID, but it’s useful because it makes querying the hierarchy way faster like no need for slow recursion! When you say many:many:many relationship, what do you mean? HID can store quite a few levels in a hierarchy

Comment: HID can be used for simple parent-child hierarchies, but not for many to many, right?